# NSClassFromString from myClass

Tags: swift

I have my custom class in extension `UIImage` like this

```
extension UIImage {   
    class AssetItem: NSObject {
    }
}
```

when I try get class from `NSClassFromString` like this

```
NSClassFromString("UIImage.AssetItem")
```

I receive `nil`. How I can do it? I need get it class from String.

---

actually I try to do a tree with names, for can get exec like it `NavigationBar.additionMenu` and receive string "NavigationBar.additionMenu".

```
protocol EIAssetRoot {
}

protocol EIAssetFolder {
    static func name(_ key: String) -> String
}

extension EIAssetFolder {

    static func name(_ key: String = #function) -> String {
        let full = "\(String(reflecting: self)).\(key)"
        let lastSpace = full.components(separatedBy: ":").last ?? full
        let components = lastSpace.components(separatedBy: ".")
        var rootComponents = components
        var rootFounding = false
        repeat {
            rootComponents = rootComponents.dropLast()
            let name = rootComponents.joined(separator: ".")
            if let anyClass = NSClassFromString(name) {
                if anyClass is EIAssetRoot {
                    rootFounding = true
                }
            }
        } while rootComponents.count > 0 && rootFounding == false

        let keyComponents = components.dropFirst(rootComponents.count)
        let name = keyComponents.joined(separator: ".")
        return name
    }

}

extension UIImage {
    @objc class AssetItem: NSObject, EIAssetRoot {
        class NavigationBar: EIAssetFolder {
            static var additionMenu: String { get { return name() } }
            static var save: String { get { return name() } }
            static let toLeft: String { get { return name() } }
            static func toRight: String { get { return name() } }
        }
    }
}
```

this I try build string from class name and trunc first part to class `EIAssetRoot`

I don't like doing in by enum because it looks like  `.NavigationBar(.Menu(.SecondMenu(.additionMenu)))` too meny `()`

Comment: Try marking the class with @objc

Comment: for `@objc class AssetItem: NSObject` not work to. How I can get class from string for swift class? any way?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [NSClassFromString returning nil for nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712055/nsclassfromstring-returning-nil-for-nested-class).

Answer (score 1):

You need to "unhide" AssetItem by moving it out of the UIImage extension and up to the top level. Objective-C can never "see" a nested type like UIImage.AssetItem — and NSClassFromString is Objective-C / Cocoa.

However, it would be even *better* to ask yourself why you need this. In Swift, an attempt to use NSClassFromString is first and foremost a Bad Smell. You are probably trying to do something here that can be done in a correct Swifty way, without involving Objective-C Cocoa at the back end. But you have not revealed what it is.

Comment: I added main my need

Comment: Unclear why you need to receive name strings.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to access the class by an explicitly defined name like this. These symbols are defined in the global scope in Objective-C (so no `.`'s are allowed in the name):

```swift
extension UIImage {
    @objc(UIImageAssetItem)
    class AssetItem: NSObject {
    }
}

let cls = NSClassFromString("UIImageAssetItem")
```